# CN1 align Label icon with regards to the baseline of its text

Tags: codenameone

In the sample given below there are three `Label` components, each having an icon image. The bounding boxes of the images are minimal (thus the image's horizontal line is at the bottom border). I would like to align those images so that their horizontal lines are on the same level as the baselines of the texts. How can I achieve this?

[image]

edit:
when applying the FlowLayout BASELINE approach I get the following result:

[image]

Note: I intentionally put the image on the right side to show that somehow a "upper basline" instead of the actual baseline is used.

edit:

when I change vAlign to BOTTOM I get the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Label` doesn't support that directly as it center aligns the image by default when it's on the left. The solution is to use two labels for each entry:

```
Label text = new Label("Text");
Label icon = new Label(image);
Container cnt = Container.encloseIn(new FlowLayout(LEFT, BASELINE), 
                              text, icon);
```

Comment: unfortunately this approach is not aligning the image with the actual baseline. See my edited post

Comment: Try `new FlowLayout(LEFT, BOTTOM)`

Comment: that's also not what I was looking for (see my edited post)

Comment: I think baseline only respects the text and doesn't work that way with images as they don't have a baseline.

Comment: Hmm how can we get the baseline of a Label text programmatically over CN1? I might put the value as bottom padding of the image which would solve it.

Comment: You can use getBaseLine which accepts the components dimensions. Notice that these might not be initialized yet when you do this... If you use flow layout try passing in the preferred size dimensions.